# Tensor algebra of $Μ$ over $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $Μ$ an $R$-module. Consider 
the $R$-module $T_{R}(M)={\displaystyle \oplus_{n=0}^{\infty}}M^{\otimes n}$ and show that it can be endowed with the structure of an $R$-algebra such 
that the following holds: there is an $R$-module homomorphism $t:M\rightarrow T_{R}(M)$ such that to any given $R$-module homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow A$ into an $R$-algebra 
$A$ there exist exactly one $R$-algebra homomorphism $L_{f}:T_{R}(M)\rightarrow A$ fulfilling $f=L_{f}t$. $T_{R}(M)$
 is called the "tensor algebra of $Μ$ over $R$ ".

I can show that it can be endowed with the structure of an $R$-algebra but the rests is difficult for me.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You surely have one idea or another on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, take the natural embedding as $t:M=M^{\otimes1}\to T_R(M)$. 
Then the condition $L_f\circ t=f$ reads as the restriction $L_f|_{M}=f$.

Now, for an $R$-module morphism $f:M\to A$ to an $R$-algebra $A$, we look for an extension $\bar f$ of $f$ on $T_R(M)$ which is an *algebra morphism*, i.e. respects the given multiplication operations. For that end, we must have
$$\bar f(m_1\otimes\dots\otimes m_k):=f(m_1)\cdot f(m_2)\cdots f(m_k)\,. $$
Note that it already proves the uniqueness of $\bar f$, as the elements $m_1\otimes\dots\otimes m_k$ form a *generating class* as $m_i\in M$ and $k\in\Bbb N$ vary.